# Change setup types in Inno Setup installer, depending on whether it's New Install or Update?

Tags: inno-setup

I created an installer with Inno Setup to install a database. My script-writing skills are quite basic. Now I need to offer updates, and need the installer to:

1. check if there is an existing installation;
2. check if an existing installation is older;
3. offer Update as option if there is an existing installation, or offer Admin or General database (new installation) as options if not.

I have pieced the code below together, which shows the three options in a dropdown/combobox. I cannot figure out how to change the options offered in the combobox on the `wpSelectComponents` page.

```pascal
[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
    OldVersion, NewVersion: String;
begin
    Result := True;

    //Check in the registry for the uninstaller of PME Database. Compare version, exit if installed version is the same or newer.
    if RegKeyExists(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{pmedatabase201}}_is1') then
    begin
        RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{pmedatabase201}}_is1', 'DisplayVersion', OldVersion)
        NewVersion := '{#MyAppVersion}'
        If NewVersion < OldVersion then
        begin
            MsgBox(('This version (' + NewVersion + ') is older than the installed version (' + OldVersion +') - setup will close.'), mbError, MB_Ok)
            Result := False;
            exit;
        end;
        If NewVersion = OldVersion then
        begin
            MsgBox(('This version (' + NewVersion + ') is the same as the installed version - setup will close.'), mbError, MB_Ok)
            Result := False;
            exit;
        end;
        If NewVersion > OldVersion then
        begin
            if MsgBox(('The database will be updated from version ' + OldVersion + ' to version ' + NewVersion + '.' + chr(13) + chr(13) + 'Continue?'), mbInformation, MB_YesNo) = idNo then
            begin
                Result := False;
                exit;
            end;
        end;
    end;
...more code, to check Windows / Office versions...

[Code]
Procedure CurPageChanged(CurPage: Integer);
begin
  if CurPage = wpSelectComponents then 
  begin
      if RegKeyExists(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{pmedatabase201}}_is1') then
      begin
//Do something: only show Update as combobox option - HOW???
      end else begin
//Do something: only show Admin and General as combobox options - HOW???
      end;
  end;
end;

[Types]
Name: "Other1"; Description: "General Database"; Languages: en
Name: "Admin1"; Description: "Administrator Database"; Languages: en
Name: "Update1"; Description: "Database update"; Languages: en
Name: "Other2"; Description: "Base de Données Générale"; Languages: fr
Name: "Admin2"; Description: "Base de Données de L'administrateur"; Languages: fr
Name: "Update2"; Description: "Mise à jour de Base de Données"; Languages: fr
Name: "Other3"; Description: "Base de Dados Geral"; Languages: pt
Name: "Admin3"; Description: "Base de Dados do Administrador"; Languages: pt
Name: "Update3"; Description: "Atualização da Base de Dados"; Languages: pt

[Components]
Name: "General"; Description: "General"; Types: other1 other2 other3; Flags: fixed disablenouninstallwarning
Name: "Admin"; Description: "Admin"; Types: admin1 admin2 admin3; Flags: fixed disablenouninstallwarning
Name: "Update"; Description: "Update"; Types: update1 update2 update3; Flags: fixed disablenouninstallwarning

[Files]
; Database files.
Source: "C:\PME SETUP\pme versions\v2.02\PME Database.accde"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: admin general update
; Data files are ONLY copied for a new installation of the central administrator database.
Source: "C:\PME SETUP\pme versions\v2.02\PME Data Storage.accdb"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: admin
Source: "C:\PME SETUP\pme versions\v2.02\PME Data Storage.accdb"; DestDir: "{app}\System Files"; Components: admin
Source: "C:\PME SETUP\pme versions\v2.02\PME Data Storage.accdb"; DestDir: "{app}\Exchange"; Components: admin 
...more follows for different component-combinations...
```

Comment: Note that you approach to localization of the Types by duplicating them is completely wrong. Consider asking new question on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck):

```pascal
[Types]
Name: "Other"; Description: "General Database"; Check: not IsUpdate
Name: "Admin"; Description: "Administrator Database"; Check: not IsUpdate
Name: "Update"; Description: "Database update"; Check: IsUpdate

[Code]

function IsUpdate: Boolean;
begin
  Result :=
    RegKeyExists(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{pmedatabase201}}_is1') and
    /*IsNewer*/;
end;
```

---

Note that you should check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` too to determine, if the application is installed already.

Comment: Sorry about that, my first time here. The RegKeyExists works. The }} is probably becasue the AppId is {{pmedatabase201}} (don't ask me why - it's from early on when everything was confusing). Check does have an effect, just not what I want, which is: not show certain components on the dropdown list.

Comment: Thanks again Martin. I had put 'Check: IsUpdate' and 'Check: not IsUpdate' in the wrong place, in [Components] instead of [Types]. Corrected that and it works: reads from the registry whether there is an existing installation; reads the version from the registry and compares; and shows appropriate 'update' or 'new install' setup types as the case may be.